# Javascript variable as function name in chain

Tags: javascript, function, variables, chaining

I am trying to pull a variable that is captured from a form element in to a function chain. The variable value needs to act as a function name. Example:

```
<form name="myform">
  <input type="radio" id="DayOfWeek" name="DayOfWeek" value="monday" />Monday
  <input type="radio" id="DayOfWeek" name="DayOfWeek" value="tuesday" />Tuesday
  <input type="radio" id="DayOfWeek" name="DayOfWeek" value="wednesday" />Wednesday
  <input type="radio" id="DayOfWeek" name="DayOfWeek" value="thursday" />Thursday
  <input type="radio" id="DayOfWeek" name="DayOfWeek" value="friday" />Friday
</form>
```

script:

```
var **monthday**=$("input[name='DayOfWeek']:checked").val();
NewDate = Date.parse(NewDate).add(1).month().**monthday**();
```

My problem has been getting the variable 'monthday' value to act as the function name in that chain. Am I having a 'duh' moment or is this not possible?

Comment: remember, in js objects are "Dictionaries", and everything is object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:`Date.parse(NewDate).add(1).month()[monthday]();`?

Comment: perfect, thanks. Was trying to string a couple together and that's where I had my problem. Should have taken out the dot that was separating the bracketed values.

Answer (score 2):

Use [bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html):

```
var monthday = $("input[name='DayOfWeek']:checked").val();
NewDate = Date.parse(NewDate).add(1).month()[monthday]();
```

Comment: you guys rock! kind-f a duh moment there. I was stringing together two captured variables and was doing:
NewDate = Date.parse(NewDate).add(1).month()[monthday]().[monthrate]();
needed to take out that second dot.
Thanks for the quick responses!